# Push to deploy with jenkins - Tooling Nodes are Offline

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jenkins, google-compute-engine

I've created a `vm` that boots with a `bitnami-jenkins` linux image as described in the official tutorial here: [Push To Deploy](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/push-to-deploy)

So far so good, I have an instance of `jenkins` up and running, successfully managed create a job (again, as described in the [Configure Jenkins](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/push-to-deploy#configure_jenkins) section ), link up the sources and the build script, however I cannot understand why the dependent nodes, are offline.

The job hangs in pending because the dependent node `cloud-dev-python` is offline:

[image: <code>cloud-dev-python</code> is offline]

I don't seem to find a reference on how it should be configured.

So my questions are :

- Do I need to setup another VM for the tooling, if so, how ?
- Since I do have remote shell access to the VM, just install the tools on the jenkins VM manually?
- Does it became online after a period of time ?